# What is "undetermined" mention in Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-ads

Is there anyone who has an idea why I find the mention "undetermined" in the statistics keywords of my Google Analytics account. This mention seems to be associated only with my display network campaign on AdWords.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with the original search which brought the visitor to your website. If instant search is enabled in Analytics under traffic sources it will show up as `(not provided)` it may be a similar situation with your campaign data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is a result of instant search, but rather the fact that Google has started blocking keyword display in Google Analytics for users that are logged in.  They state that this is a privacy concern and the best way to access search terms is through Webmaster Tools instead.

This post has some more detailed information about it: http://searchengineland.com/the-transition-from-search-term-data-to-not-provided-chrome-is-the-next-data-source-to-make-the-switch-145644